# Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]

Tags: wcf

I know already Many of them getting this same error. I tried all the possible answers given here but i am still getting this error.

My Web.config for the service.

```
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AjaxServiceHttpsBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled ="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AjaxServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="AjaxService"  behaviorConfiguration="AjaxServiceHttpsBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://servername/websitefolder" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"  binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpsBinding" contract="AjaxService" />
        </service>
    </services>
        <bindings>
   <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpsBinding">
        <security mode="Transport"></security>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
   <basicHttpBinding>
```

The service is located at "https://servername/websitefolder/AjaxService.svc" and ssl is configured correctly.

is my Base Address is wrong? I have only one End point for this service. I tried all the possible combinations but still I am getting this error.

Comment: If you want to access your service over https then just configure it for http initially on IIS and then configure https on your virtual directory to access the service over https. I dont think if you are hosting on IIS you would need the baseaddress element in your config. Also your service name should be a fully qualified name

Comment: I am getting the same scenarios and errors stated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462083/wcf-webservice-with-spring-net-could-not-find-base-address-scheme-http?rq=1 only difference is the service I used is simple ajax service hosted on same website to call an external service. I also set up the same environment (with ssl on iis) in my dev machine which is working fine with out giving any base address. But its not working on Production server with the same web.config settings.

Comment: Please use fully qualified names for your service name and endpoint contract values. They need to be namespace.AjaxService and namespace.IAjaxService.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. When the service was configured as http i am getting an access denied error when i was using asp:ScriptManager to access the service trough javascript. That's why i tried to change the service into https . Another issue is the hosted website which using the service is accessed through an iframe from a main website. I guess that may be reason why the base address is need to be configured correctly?

Comment: Sorry I changed the original service name and end point contract values to post question here. They are all fully qualified Names.

Comment: If its a REST service then make sure your service URL has the resource name appended to the URL for accessing and also it sets the proper content type. Access denied might be due to some authentication as well so make sure that your autentication information is passed from your client side call

Comment: This is the exact reason why i changed the service into secured. http://www.craigwardman.com/blog/index.php/2008/11/scriptmanager-service-reference-and-https/ when I am trying to access the "https://servername/websitefolder/AjaxService.svc/jsdebug" the javascrpt inside uses http instead of https to access the service. Thats the reason why access is denied message. All Authentications are fine.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue with wsHttpBinding, and found it wasn't a problem with my base address at all but what I had defined in my  element

```
 <wsHttpBinding><binding name="wsHttpBinding_Administration">
      <security mode="Message"> <!-- changed this to "message" -->
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: I dont get how this works when **The enumeration value must be one of the following: None, Transport, TransportCredentialOnly.**

Answer (score 0):

Check bindings of your website inside of IIS. https binding should be added there.